# Unable to boot from USB stick on my ubuntu PC

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I am trying to install windows on my pc. I have configured the BIOS settings to boot from usb drive. Each time I do a restart, ubuntu still shows up on my screen. I have changed the boot order to boot from USB stick first.

I have used the same usb drive to install windows on my other pc so the usb drive cannot be the issue. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I was about to shut down, but this is a common theme in questions here.  Here's a link to a crude search that will get you started: https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+linux+boot+usb+install+windows

Comment: Test if the computer can boot from the USB drive at all (disable all other bootmedia in the BIOS or remove it physicaly). You should also include additional detail to you're question e.g. screenshots, further HW specifications, etc.

Comment: By installing Windows on a PC with Ubuntu, you will likely loose everything on the drive created or downloaded with Ubuntu. You didn't say you have backed up your PC, so please allow me to strongly suggest you should!

Answer (score 1):

Mate, use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html) to burn the ISO properly. I swear by this tiny app, had the same problem with some ISO's, once with Windows 10 and I was due to the way I burned the ISO in the ThumbDrive. Someone recommended me Rufus, which solved my problem and I have been using it pretty much since then. This are the steps I usually follow:

- Pick your Thumb Drive
- Set "Partition scheme" to "MBR"
- Leave the "Target system" to default "BIOS or UEFI"
- Set "File System" to FAT32. I find it way more compatible than let's say NTFS.
- Start

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try different USB ports. If you don't find one that works, look for the hot key that allows you to select boot device on startup. In Dell computers it's F12. Sometimes I've worked with computers where the USB disk is not visible unless you plug it in AFTER power on.

Comment: I tried that. Even after selecting the boot device, ubuntu still shows up

Comment: Then, the only reason I can think about for not to boot from USB is that USB is not bootable. You can check it from Ubuntu Disks utility. If you could boot the other computer from that USB disk, maybe something happened to it after that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did eventually:

I enabled UEFI boot mode, selected UEFI File under boot options, navigated to the boot.exe file which was part of the windows ISO in my usb stick and voila! I was able to boot into windows. But before I could install windows, I had to format my hard drive to the GPT partition. Thanks guys for your help